# Как отменить async таймер Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram, асинхронность

Нужно сделать так, чтобы по команде `/close` останавливался таймер.
Буду благодарен если вы мне поможете.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import random
import asyncio

bot = Bot(..., parse_mode='HTML') 
dp = Dispatcher(bot,storage=MemoryStorage())

@dp.message_handler(text='вернуться назад')
@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Добро пожаловать, это бот-помощник.', reply_markup=mainkb)

@dp.message_handler(commands='timer')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Вы открыли режим Timer.', reply_markup=timerkb)

@dp.message_handler(text='30 секунд')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f'засек <b>30 секунд</b>', reply_markup=closekb)
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
    await message.answer(f'<b>30 секунд</b> истекло!')

@dp.message_handler(text='1 минута')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f'засек <b>1 минуту</b>', reply_markup=closekb)
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
    await message.answer(f'<b>1 минута</b> истекло!')

@dp.message_handler(text='5 минут')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f'засек <b>5 минут</b>', reply_markup=closekb)
    await asyncio.sleep(300)
    await message.answer(f'<b>5 минут</b> истекло!')

@dp.message_handler(commands='close')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Таймер отменен.', reply_markup=timerkb)

executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы уверены что случайно не сотрете стейт `state.finish` то можно вот так. Если не уверены, то можно сделать просто глобальный словарь и делать в целом то же самое.

```
@dp.message_handler(text='30 секунд')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f'засек <b>30 секунд</b>', reply_markup=closekb)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['timer'] = True
    
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
    
    if (await state.get_data('timer')) is True:  
        await message.answer(f'<b>30 секунд</b> истекло!')
        await state.set_data({'timer': None})


@dp.message_handler(commands='close')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Таймер отменен.', reply_markup=timerkb)
    await state.set_data({'timer': None})
```